# wstring_buffer not giving output

Tags: c++

The following program is originally from Josuttis' book "The C++ Standard Library", 2nd Ed, pg 903.

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cab87d0d7d9f8a7b

```
/**
    An input stream reads UTF-8 multibyte characters into wide characters.
    Then, an output stream writes these wide characters as UTF-16 
    multibyte characters with leading byte order marks.
*/

#include <string>
#include <iostream>             /// cout
#include <locale>               /// wbuffer_convert
#include <codecvt>              /// codecvt_utf8<T>>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // create input stream reading UTF-8 sequences:
    wbuffer_convert<codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> 
             utf8inBuf(cin.rdbuf());
    wistream utf8in(&utf8inBuf);

    // create output stream writing UTF-16 sequences:
    wbuffer_convert<codecvt_utf16<wchar_t,
                                  0xFFFF,
                                  generate_header>>
                   utf16outBuf(cout.rdbuf());
    wostream utf16out(&utf16outBuf);

    // write each character read:
    wchar_t c;
    while (utf8in.get(c))
    {
        utf16out.put(c);
    }

    cout << "Completed!" << endl;
}
```

Given the following input:

```
Hello, World!
```

the program doesn't print any corresponding output.

Why is this happening? How do I get the program to work?

Comment: What is your platform? [edit] your question and make that clear please.

Comment: It does for me, what output do you expect?

Comment: The platform is http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com. I had posted a link to the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this work on Ubuntu. 
I had to add this line at the very beginning, right after `main`:

```
std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
```

otherwise the `utf8inBuf` buffer wasn't filled from `cin`.

And flush the output stream with:

```
utf16out << flush;
```

at the very end, after the `while` loop.

Comment: Yes. That's the [right answer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a42651778fd45417).